# Vue.js2 - Object.assign({}, this.var) preventing watch method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

returning this.user (a global computed property) works as expected. Of course, I'm making a copy because I do not want to overwrite the actual user data. So, I'm using Object.assign. However, once I include return Object.assign({}, this.user) (opposed to this.user), the watch method no longer functions.

Here is my template (I am using bootstrap-vue):

```
<template>
  <form role="form">
    <b-form-group
      label="First Name"
      label-for="basicName"
      :label-cols="3"
      :horizontal="true">
        <b-form-input id="user-name-first" type="text" v-model="userFormData.fname"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
          <b-form-group
      label="Last Name"
      label-for="basicName"
      :label-cols="3"
      :horizontal="true">
        <b-form-input id="user-name-lirst" type="text" v-model="userFormData.lname"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
          <b-form-group
      label="Email"
      label-for="user-email"
      :label-cols="3"
      :horizontal="true">
        <b-form-input id="user-email" type="text" v-model="userFormData.email"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group
          :label-cols="3"
          :horizontal="true">
                    <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Save changes</b-button>
            <b-button type="button" variant="secondary" @click="userFormCancel">Cancel</b-button>
        </b-form-group>
      </form>
</template>
```

So, this works and sets **editsPending** to **true** whenever changes are applied to **userProfile** (via v-model on an input)

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'userProfile',
  data () {
    return {
      editsPending: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    userFormData: function () {
      return this.user
    }
  },
  watch: {
    userFormData: {
      deep: true,
      handler (val) {
        this.editsPending = true
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    userFormCancel () {
      this.editsPending = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

...but this does not; **userFormData** becomes a clone of **user** but **editsPending** is not affected by updates to **userFormData**.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'userProfile',
  data () {
    return {
      editsPending: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    userFormData: function () {
      return Object.assign({}, this.user)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    userFormData: {
      deep: true,
      handler (val) {
        this.editsPending = true
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    userFormCancel () {
      this.editsPending = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Can anyone explain why this may be happening and suggest a viable solution?

Comment: what kind of changes are you trying to watch ? inputs ?

Comment: yes, as stated; "whenever changes are applied to userProfile (via v-model on an input)."

Comment: i tried to reproduced your issue in a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/zu3b2cmk/) but the watch works, maybe the problem is somewhere else. Where the user is coming from ?

Comment: I created a global mixin that sets the computed prop "user" from my store's state.user value, which is a single-level object containing one array. That all works just fine if I do not use Object.assign, though. It isn't until I add Object.assign that things break. -__-

Comment: I even removed the one array, JIC that was creating an issue but the results did not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its
> dependencies have changed. ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods))

That's why it works with `return this.user` and not with `Object.assign` because it's not a reactive dependency.

If you want reactive data you should initialize `userFormData` as an empty object data and assign your user when your Vue instance is created:

```
  data () {
    return {
      editsPending: false,
      userFormData: {}
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.userFormData = Object.assign({}, this.user)
  },
```

Comment: Yes. This works as expected. @aur%c3%a9lien-bottazini also pointed this out eventually but I will mark this as the answer as it immediately points out the issue and solution. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a solution for the next issue, which is how to revert the data back to the user data upon cancel after form data has been edited? I have a watch method on editsPending, which works fine, but this.userFormData = Object.assign({}, this.user) does nothing within the  watch method (no reactivity, setting the form back to its original state).

Comment: @user2220551 how do you want to trigger your revert action ? when you click on "Cancel" or when you empty an input ?

Comment: Actually, I have that working now. Everything works except one thing; editsPending is still not being affected by the watch method.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9bm1d1vt/ Notice that editsPending never gets set to true

Comment: it never sets to true because you are watching `user` not `userFormData` which is the reactive data in the template. By changing the watcher, you can notice that `editsPending` is now always set to `true`. It's because Vue performs DOM updates asynchronously and `userFormData` is assign/reassign in the created hook and in the cancel method and by that, always watched. To prevent this behavior you can callback `this.editsPending = false` with the `nextTick()` method.

Comment: OK, I've been at this for too long. I was watching user instead of userFormData. But this is still not working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/rLw9e51h/ This is why I was trying to use a computed property for formUserData - once the created hook is called, so is the watch. And from there, nothing seems to work. Perhaps I'm just going about this all wrong.

Comment: Ah ha. Yes, I forgot about the nextTick method. I will try that.

Comment: Yes! Thank You!!! I am very fresh to Vue still and am doing my best to absorb it all. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Tested different things to reproduce the behaviour you see.

I suspect that in your template your are binding your inputs to `UserFormdata` (incorrect)

```
<input v-model="userFormData.name">
```

Instead of (correct)

```
<input v-model="user.name">
```

If you could share your template that would help ;)

Edit: After template addition.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      editsPending: false,
      user: { name: 'John Doe' },
      userCachedData: {},
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.userCachedData = Object.assign({}, this.user);
  },
  watch: {
    user: {
      deep: true,
      handler (val) {
        this.editsPending = true
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    userFormCancel () {
      this.editsPending = false
    }
  }
})

<div id="app">
  {{ user }}
  {{ userCachedData }}
  <br>
  <input v-model="user.name" />
  {{ this.editsPending }}
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/aurelien-bottazini/pen/BVNJaG?editors=1010

Comment: But "user" is a store object that I do not wish to modify until the form is successfully submitted. Then I would modify my user object via an action. Why do you say that binding my form inputs to userFormData is incorrect?

Comment: I have added my tpl

Comment: Because it seems odd to use a computed property as your v-model. It works because in your working version your computed property = user (from data)

Comment: Actually, "user" is also a computed property from my store's state object, as demonstrated; https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html.

After the form is submitted, I will use a store action to save the data. But first, I'm just trying to use a copy of the store's user data to pre-fill the user form.

Comment: I see that your example in codepen works but isn't it bad practice to directly manipulate store data? this.user is a computed property receiving data from one of my store's getter methods.

Comment: yes. That's true. I did not know your user was inside your store as it was never mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $emit to assign value to object:

```
mounted() {
  this.$emit("userFormData", this.user);
}
```